# Compute a chain of service calls by input parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, service

The task is to call the target service by the input params. I have a name of the target service and some input params:

```
targetServiceName: service_D           // which has these input params: param_2, param_3, param_6
commonInputParams: param_1, param_2    // not enough for the target service call
```

At the beginning of the call, I may not have the necessary params to call the target service. And I have to get the params to call the target service by computing a sequence of service calls for getting the input params of the target service.

I have several services:

```
service_A
service_B
service_C
service_D
```

Every service has input and output params:

```
         (param_1, param_2) => service_A => (param_3, param_4)
         (param_1, param_3) => service_B => (param_4, param_5)
                  (param_1) => service_C => (param_3, param_4, param_6)
(param_2, param_3, param_6) => service_D => (param_7)
```

As shown earlier, output param of one service can be input param of another.
Next to the services there is their configuration, help us to compute chain of service calls, to help us achieve the target service.

```
services:
  service_A:
    inputParams:
      - param_1
      - param_2
    outputParams:
      - param_3
      - param_4
  service_B:
    inputParams:
      - param_1
      - param_3
    outputParams:
      - param_4
      - param_5
  service_C:
    inputParams:
      - param_1
    outputParams:
      - param_3
      - param_4
      - param_6
  service_D:
    inputParams:
      - param_2
      - param_3
      - param_6
    outputParams:
      - param_7
```

The result of all that is the output params of the target service.

I think to build graph and use dfs algorithm to compute service sequence. I know how to do it for services with a single input param, but I don't quite sure how to do it for multiple params for each service.

Steps that I guess:

1. Receive request with the target service name and several input params.
2. Checking or validation: is it possible to reach out to the target service with current input params.
3. If it possible then make a sequenced service calls and collect missed params.
4. Then call the target service and get final result params.
5. Return final result params and finish.

How to make sequenced path of services (build correct graph), when I have multiple input params per service, not single?

Implementing language is java/kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I would consider in a situation like this.

### Quick and dirty

You can keep track of all parameters that are already computed. On each turn, iterate through all uncalled services in any order until you find one you can call with your current set of available parameters. Call it and update the computed parameters and uncalled services. End when there are no more services to call.

Pseudocode:

```
pendingServices = HashSet(...)
computedParams = HashMap()
while !pendingServices.isEmpty() {
    for service in pendingServices {
        if computedParams.containsAll(service.getInputs()) {
            pendingServices.remove(service)
            inputs = computedParams.get(service.getInputs())
            outputs = service.run()
            computedParams.putAll(outputs)
            break
        }
        throw new CyclicalDependencyException()
    }
}
// All services ran, outputs are available in computedParams
```

This is easy enough to implement and it supports adding or removing services at runtime. However, it runs in O(N^2) time, and detecting cyclical dependencies before running the services requires additional computation (dry-running the whole algorithm is one way of doing that).

### Properly

Construct a directed graph of dependencies, [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) it and run services in that order. This approach is more efficient and it finds cycles before committing to execution, but at the cost of slightly higher code complexity, especially if runtime modification of the service list is necessary.

Comment: I had supposed to use topological sorting, but what to do when we have multiple parameters per service, but not just single. How to build graph when multiple params?

Comment: Consider a graph where an arrow points from service X to service Y if and only if Y depends on a parameter that X (perhaps non-exclusively) supplies. Do you allow cycles in the resulting graph? If you don't, then you can use this graph in your program. If you do, that's a more difficult question. An example of a reasonable cycle: consider Egg (in 1, out 2), Chicken (in 2, out 1) and Dinosaur (out 1). In this case, the above graph would contain a cycle, [Egg, Chicken], but it could be ran the following way: [Dinosaur, Egg, Chicken].